# NSPersistentDocument "Unsupported store type" Exception

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, osx-lion, nspersistentdocument

I've run into this problem twice now: Xcode 4.1, Lion, and a NSPersistentDocument Core Data project.

My program was running fine until I added two "binary data" attributes to one of the entities in my model. Now, when I run the app and try to save the document, an exception is thrown from within `configurePersistentStoreCoordinatorForURL:ofType:modelConfiguration:storeOptions:error:`.

The last time I started getting this error, it was when I updated a setting in the project's target settings. At that time, resetting the altered setting had no effect, I had to restore the Xcode project file from a backup and then it worked - so it wasn't code related.

This is the log at the time the exception is thrown:

```
2011-08-27 17:34:00.867 MyAppName[5690:707] Unsupported store type.
2011-08-27 17:34:00.879 MyAppName[5690:707] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ae0e986 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8e28cd5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreData                            0x00007fff9576776a -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:] + 1530
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff9190af88 -[NSPersistentDocument configurePersistentStoreCoordinatorForURL:ofType:modelConfiguration:storeOptions:error:] + 554
    4   MyAppName                            0x0000000100001af4 -[MyAppNameDocument configurePersistentStoreCoordinatorForURL:ofType:modelConfiguration:storeOptions:error:] + 244
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff91bc6697 -[NSPersistentDocument(NSDeprecatedInternal) _configurePersistentStoreCoordinatorForURL:ofType:error:] + 172
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff91909a82 -[NSPersistentDocument writeToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:originalContentsURL:error:] + 418
    7   MyAppName                            0x0000000100001c51 -[MyAppNameDocument writeToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:originalContentsURL:error:] + 161
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff917c5062 -[NSDocument _writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:forceTemporaryDirectory:error:] + 581
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff917aeaba -[NSDocument _writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:error:] + 27
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff917c4e0b -[NSDocument writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:error:] + 344
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff919095d1 -[NSPersistentDocument writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:error:] + 1073
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff917cdee4 __-[NSDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_8 + 329
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff917cd5ca __-[NSDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_14 + 451
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff917cdcbd __-[NSDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_7 + 1459
    15  Foundation                          0x00007fff94079f34 -[NSFileCoordinator(NSPrivate) _invokeAccessor:orDont:thenRelinquishAccessClaimForID:] + 202
    16  Foundation                          0x00007fff9407cdd5 -[NSFileCoordinator(NSPrivate) _coordinateWritingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:] + 663
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff917c3754 -[NSDocument _fileCoordinator:coordinateReadingContentsAndWritingItemAtURL:byAccessor:] + 336
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff917b1bb3 __-[NSDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_1 + 845
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff917acbda -[NSDocument continueFileAccessUsingBlock:] + 227
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff917c7413 -[NSDocument _performFileAccessOnMainThread:usingBlock:] + 466
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff917c716b -[NSDocument performAsynchronousFileAccessUsingBlock:] + 304
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff917b1860 -[NSDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:] + 91
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff917b0555 __-[NSDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:delegate:didSaveSelector:contextInfo:]_block_invoke_2 + 131
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff917be5e0 -[NSDocument _commitEditingThenContinue:] + 337
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fff91908d32 __-[NSPersistentDocument _documentEditor:didCommit:withContext:]_block_invoke_1 + 53
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8adc3b5c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ad7bc52 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 322
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ada3d37 __CFRunLoopRun + 2023
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ada3216 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
    30  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8ce604ff RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 277
    31  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8ce67b73 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 181
    32  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8ce67aae BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
    33  AppKit                              0x00007fff91410191 _DPSNextEvent + 659
    34  AppKit                              0x00007fff9140fa95 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 135
    35  AppKit                              0x00007fff9140c3d6 -[NSApplication run] + 463
    36  AppKit                              0x00007fff9168a52a NSApplicationMain + 867
    37  MyAppName                            0x00000001000012e2 main + 34
    38  MyAppName                            0x00000001000012b4 start + 52
)
```

I'm currently using an SQLite store type. I also tried removing the attributes that I added to the entity, but I get the same result. I also cleared all caches, cleaned the project, and delete the DerivedData folder . I also turned off `autosavesInPlace`. I feel like this is some sort of Xcode bug.

Has anyone seen this before? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same happened to me. Actually the bug in Xcode is the following (at least in my case): when setting the value for the key "Core Data persistent store type" (NSPersistentStoreTypeKey) by selecting it from the pop up menu in the nice UI for Document Types (Target -> Info), Xcode sets the value to the string "NSSQLiteStoreType" (for example) instead of "SQLite".

Fixing this directly in the Info.plist did work for me (no need to recreate the project from scratch).

Comment: Still not fixed in XCode Version 4.5.1 (4G1004) ... does somebody create a bug report at apple and/or can provide a openradar id?

Comment: Bug with apple - rdar://17410404

Comment: In Xcode 14.2  "Core Data persistent store type" doesn't appear in the dropdown, but adding `NSPersistentStoreTypeKey` manually to the Info.plist Document section and setting it to `SQLite` works. The "click here to add key" doesn't work in the target/info/document screen, there is nothing to click. Clicking the + below results in a new document type which is a pain to get rid of because there is no -.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question. It is an Xcode bug. Go figure. How frustrating.

I backed-up all my source code, recreated a new project from scratch, copied my source code back into the project and ran it. Everything works now.

Glad to know it's not me at least.