# Preload sqlite to core data

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I am trying to preload data to core data at the first run with a `sqlite` file. I first created a `xcdatamodeld` file, and then use python to produce the `sqlite` database, which has exactly the same data structure with the `xcdatamodeld` I stated.

```
@main
struct ArgosApp: App {
    
    
    static var isFirstLaunch = isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce()

      // MARK:- Initialise Core Data Stack
    
       var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Argos")

        // if it is, load data from sql
        if ArgosApp.isFirstLaunch {
            
            guard let seededDataURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "karate", withExtension: "sqlite") else {
                fatalError("Fail to find")
            }
            let storeUrl = ArgosApp.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("karate.sqlite")
            
            if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: (storeUrl.path)) {
                try! FileManager.default.copyItem(at: seededDataURL, to: storeUrl)
            }
            
            let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
            description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
            description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
            description.url = storeUrl
            description.type = "sqlite"

            container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
                
            // ERROR came in here: Thread 1: "Unsupported store type."
            container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
                if let error = error as NSError? {
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                }
            })
            return container
        }
        
        // else, load from core data
        else {
            container.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in
              if let error = error as NSError? {
                // TODO:- More decent error handling
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
              }
            }
        }
        return container
    }()

        
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            let context = persistentContainer.viewContext

            let categories = Category.fetchAllCategories(context: context) ?? []
            // Pass the persistent container to the view as environment object
            ChallengeChooser(categories: categories)
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext
                             ,context)
        }
    }
    
    
    // Detect if it's the first-launch
    
    static func isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce() -> Bool {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let _ = defaults.string(forKey: "isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce") {
            print("App already launched")
            return false
        } else {
            defaults.set(true, forKey: "isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce")
            print("App launched first time")
            return true
        }
    }
    
    func saveContext (context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    static func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        return documentsDirectory
    }
}
```

The error came in when I tried to load the database saying

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported store type.'
```

Here is the code I ran with sqlite3, I add some test data on it so the `difficulty` and `explanation` column are all NULL.

```
cur.execute("""
CREATE TABLE category (
  name VARCHAR(40) PRIMARY KEY
  );
 """)
cur.execute("""
CREATE TABLE video (
  url VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY,
  explanation VARCHAR(300),
  difficulty INT,
  category VARCHAR(40),
  FOREIGN KEY(category) REFERENCES category(name)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  );
 """)
```

And this is what my `xcdatamodeld` looks like, and I set `name` and `url` to be non optional.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217572/nspersistentdocument-unsupported-store-type-exception?rq=1 ? Use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentstore/persistent_store_types ? `description.type = NSSQLiteStoreType`? which in my test is `SQLite` not `sqlite` (case sensitive I guess?)

Comment: "...then use python to produce the sqlite database..." Please explain the detail of how you do this.  The format CoreData uses for its sqlite store is proprietary (there's more to it than the simple table structure).

Comment: @Larme Thanks!!!! It is! Is this the correct way of loading ```sqlite``` database? Since after I fix this, I still cannot fetch any data. I checked my ```sqlite``` file, it is in the document folder and full of data. Is it a problem with my ```sqlite``` file, or am I missing some steps?

Comment: @pbasdf Yes thanks you are right, I am actually not familiar with sql, so I might be wrong with it. I update my sql code and data model as well

Comment: You cannot create the SQLite file like that.  The only way (reliably) to create a CoreData SQLite file is using the CoreData API.  You will need to create a helper app on your Mac that reads your Sqlite file (using SQLite) then writes to a CoreData database (using the usual CoreData persistent store and stack).

Comment: @pbasdf what do you mean by reads your Sqlite file (using SQLite)? Why is it not possible to do in current app?

Comment: Because CoreData is not a tool for reading SQLite files.  It’s a tool for managing objects and their relationships, which happens to use SQLite as (one of) its persistence mechanisms.  The structure of the SQLite files it uses is not something you can create in Python.

Comment: @pbasdf could you plz give me more clues on this implementation? Like some key words to search for?

Comment: If you search here on SO for “[core-data] pre populate” you will find some good Q&As on this topic.

Comment: @JINGYAHAN Core Data's SQLite schema is not what you expect it to be, which is why this doesn't work. The schema is also undocumented. The best way to create a pre-populated persistent store is to use Core Data to create it. If you want to use regular SQLite, you can do that in iOS instead of Core Data.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424362/core-data-relationship-with-prepopulated-sqlite for one example